# CakePHP, including entire jquery plugin folder (with css, etc)?

Tags: jquery, plugins, cakephp, include

I need to use some fairly complex Jquery plugins that aren't just a single .js file, but rather need an entire folder that contains css, images, etc.. I am not understanding how to include this using cakephp, I suppose I could do it from the layout in a traditional HTML manner, but it would be nicer to just do it the Cakephp way, the jquery plugin tells me to do this to include the folder:

```
<link id="bespin_base" href="/path/to"/>
```

But I don't quite get how to do this in cakephp.. would it be my server-side path, such as "/var/www/jquery/plugin.. etc"?  Thanks for any info..

the way I normally include a jquery plugin is just like this, and similar for css but I don't want to have to manually include each file:

```
echo $html->script('plugin', false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tend to do, because I prefer to maintain the Cake structure is place any `.js` files in `app/webroot/js/` and place related assets in their corresponding Cake directory (e.g. `app/webroot/css` or `app/webroot/img`). Usually, this means modifying the plugin's CSS so that any `url()` declarations point to `/img/...` rather than the relative path that they usually have by default.

If you don't mind being "atypical" and want to keep it simply, then just drop everything into `app/webroot/js/jquery/plugin-name/` (or something similar of your own creation). That will mix js, css and images in one directory, but there's nothing *wrong* with that, per se. Then, using your HTML helper, you'd reference:

```
echo $html->script( 'jquery/plugin-name/plugin-file.js', false );
```

(precise syntax may vary slightly)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a folder in your webroot path, and access things out of it all you need to do is put a / in front of your path.

If you put a / in front of your path it makes it relative to the webroot folder otherwise it makes it relative to your JS folder.

Example

```
$this->Html->script( '/thirdparty/jquery/file' ); // Is equal to URL/webroot/thirdparty/jquery/file.js
```

Where

```
$this->Html->script( 'jquery/file' ); // Is equal to URL/webroot/js/jquery/file.js
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that code is usually best presented indented by 4 spaces so it looks like it does now.  You can type or paste the code into the edit box (no tabs), then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all by 4 spaces.